# Clearing input field in JavaScript after click event

Tags: javascript, dom, input

I made a simple list items page with JavaScript. And everything works just as expected. What I want is that, every time I add a new list-item, the input field should be cleared. As in the value should be deleted.

```js
function addItem() {

  if (document.querySelector('.text-input').value) {

    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.className = 'list-item'
    var input = document.querySelector('.text-input').value;
    listItem.textContent = input;
    document.querySelector('.list').appendChild(listItem);
    document.querySelector('.text-input').value = '';


  }

}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

And I actually achieved what I wanted with that last line of code in the addItem callback function. However instead of writing `document.querySelector('.text-input').value = '';`, if I write `input = '';`, it doesn't work. And this is not making any sense to me cause I declared that variable within that function and also used it for `listItem.textContent = input`; as you can see.

Comment: Because this `var input = document.querySelector('.text-input').value` it's a variable declaration initialized with a value.  Doing this `input = ''` is only re-assigning another value.  Probably you're confused about referencing the attribute `value`.

Comment: Please, start write the code in declared variables style. Does not use such "direct" way of coding, because maintain and debug will occurs with a lot of an errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this `var input = document.querySelector('.text-input').value` it's a variable declaration initialized with a value.  Doing this `input = ''` is only re-assigning another value.  You're confused about referencing the attribute `value`.

**What you probably want to do is:**

```
const listItem = document.createElement('li');
listItem.className = 'list-item'

var input = document.querySelector('.text-input'); // Get a reference of element text-input

listItem.textContent = input.value; //Use the current value of text-input.
document.querySelector('.list').appendChild(listItem); 

input.value = ''; // Modify the value of the text-input's reference.
```

Comment: @MagneticKode exactly :-)